# LIP - Minimum Spanning Tree Cutset Formulation

Tags: graphs, linear-programming, integer-programming

I just started learning about linear programming in my class, and I'm having some trouble understanding the MST Formulation Integer Linear Programming (Cutset Formulation).

This is the definition:

[image]

[image]

$x_{ij}$ is defined to be $1$ if the edge $ij$ is in $T$.

What exactly does the optimum value represent here? Is it the number of edges that are used in our MST? If so, how does knowing the # of edges help us in forming the MST?

How does this LP "work" to find the MST problem? Thank you.